# Multi signers with conditions

Tags: docusignapi

I will add 4 recipients to digitally sign the document. Is there any way where if 3 of 4 recipients sign the document can be considered as complete signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have a recipient who is an "Editor" or an "Intermediary" recipient--they would then decide if the additional people need to sign or not.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not have the optional recipients feature.

Your integration should handle the case of conditional recipients and create the envelope with the exact number of recipients.

---

DocuSign supports other types of  recipients. You  can consider using them

- [Carbon Copy](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#carbon-copies-recipient)

> **Carbon copy** recipients get a copy of the envelope but don't need to sign, initial, date or add information to any of the documents. This type of recipient can be used in any routing order. Carbon copy recipients receive their copy of the envelope when the envelope reaches the recipient's order in the process flow and when the envelope is completed.

- [Certified Delivery](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#certified-deliveries-recipient)

> **Certified delivery** recipients must receive the completed documents for the envelope to be completed. However, they don't need to sign, initial, date or add information to any of the documents.